# jQuery AJAX struggle

Tags: jquery, html

I searched the internet until I went blue but cannot figure this out and why it is not working.

I have javascript but this is only working for firefox. no other browser.

SO, I decided to go to jQuery.

What I want to do is this:
- I have a folder.
- In this folder, I have an html.html file. This is my main website.
- then I have a file home.html.

html.html looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Struggeling with jQuery ajax! *******
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div="one">
            Load the page here
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and home.html looks like this:

```
    <html>
        <head>

        </head>
        <body>
            Please load this into the div! (this text will be displayed in other words)
        </body>
    </html>
```

how on earth can I get this using jQuery? Please help me. I cannot get this right.

=====================================================================================

OK, so this is how it looks like right now. In my file, I have home.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Struggeling with jQuery ajax! *******
        </title>
        <script language="javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#one").load("html.html body");
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="one">
            Load the page here
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I downloaded the development version of jQuery and this is a file (jQuery.js) where home.html is located.

then in the other html.html looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        Please load this into the div! (this text will be displayed in other words)
    </body>
</html>
```

but this is not working. I dont get the "Please load this into the div! (this text will be displayed in other words)"

Comment: I believe you can use the `.load()` function in jQuery.

Comment: So you have javascript, you've searched, decided to go with jQuery, and still have no code to post ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#one").load("home.html body");
});
</script>
```

Also, update your html.html (I dont like this name, btw, use index.html for a main page) target div ID.

```
<div id="one"></div>
```

Edit: I also see no place where you reference your jQuery lib, be sure to do that!

Comment: Also needs to update html.html to have the div id="one" not div="one".

Comment: Haha, I just saw that, nice catch.

Comment: I made a edit to me post. please see. I dont get it. its not working.

Answer (score 0):

First give your div a proper ID.

```
<div id="one">
    Load the page here
</div>
```

Then use jQuery to get and load, using the [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

```
$('#one').load('folder/html.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Also remove any "doubled" tags.  In other words when you insert `html.html` you don't want:

```
<div id="one">
     <html>
          <body>
               Stuff
          </body>
     </html>
</div>
```

It'll look ugly and could cause issues. So remove those extra `<html>` and `<body>` tags.